# kobuki teleop problem

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, kobuki, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have problem with teleop by keyboard. After bring up kobuki
*roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch*, I cannot teleop by keyboard using
*roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch*. However *roslaunch kobuki_keyop safe_keyop.launch* works well. Could you explain for me? it seems ros packet for turtlebot 1 is not running for kuboki ( I also tested with turtlebot_follower and gmapping_demo and it didn't worked on kobuki). Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68818/kobuki-teleop-problem/) by [WB](https://answers.ros.org/users/3727/wb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-25**:
Please tag your questions with already existing tags or if not suitable with new ones. In that way people will more likely find your question and answer it (because many use tag-filtered email notifications).

**Comment by [WB](https://answers.ros.org/users/3727/wb/) on 2013-07-25**:
Thanks for remind me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I tested all the packages from the tutorial on a Turtlebot 2 and they were all working (except the Panorama one because I missed a library and didn't want to install it).

Did you start the teleoperation from turtlebot_teleop through ssh ? This might be the source of your troubles if you haven't.

But you can't use packets from the Turtlebot 1 on kobuki since many topics (and some other things I guess too) have been changed. So you need to install the ones which were released for the Turtlebot 2.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WB](https://answers.ros.org/users/3727/wb/) on 2013-07-25**:
yes I started tele through ssh, but it's working now. Thanks for reply.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-25**:
@WB Please mark your question as answered, if all your problems are resolved. To do so, click on the checker sign to the left of the answer, which you like most.